# Как сделать 2д освещение?

Tags: unity3d

Хочу сделать освещение как на скрине ниже: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Тут видно как решетка, как бы, мешает распространению света, а так же сверху и снизу лучей виден относительно резкий переход, а в месте, где заканчиваются лучи очень плавный переход (надеюсь нормально объяснил). Пытался делать через freeform light 2d с добавление другого объекта, который не пропускает свет, но выходит не очень. Использую версию 2020.3.44f1

Comment: Нарисуйте в графическом редакторе.

Comment: Да, свет на скришоте нарисованный, а не сгенерированный освещением. Дело в типе смешивания, для такого света используют `additive blending`,а картинка на самом деле ч/б, без альфы.

Comment: @Yaroslav, тут видно что спрайты персонажа используют карту нормалей. Можно ли что-то сделать в параметрах света, чтобы он не влиял на окружение, а только на персонажа? А то как-то ярко получится.

Comment: Это зависит исключительно от материала, а не света.